# Debug element not showing HTML of child component

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am trying to see the HTML of the child component when using `fixture.debugElement`. When I `console.log(fixture.debugElement)` I only see the tag of the child component but not the HTML it contains.

**Parent template**

```
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<child-component *ngIf="show"></child-component>
```

**Child template**

```
<p>Some Text</p>
```

**Parent spec**

```
it('should render child component', () => {
   component.show = true;
   fixture.detectChanges();
   console.log(comonent.debugElement);
   // Child component appears empty like this: <child-component></child-component>
});
```

I expect to see the HTML of the child component.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the `ChildComponent` as well, you have to include it in the declarations array of `TestBed.configureTestingModule`.

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            // !! include child component here
            declarations: [ParentComponent, ChildComponent]
        }).compileComponents();
```